# SetColumnError in various rows at the same time

Tags: c#, devexpress, multiple-columns

I worked with the  `SetColumnError` method sometimes, and for my experience I know when the row loses the focus the icons dissapears.

What I want now is show the same error icons at the same time in various cells in differents row of course. Something like this :

```
for (int i = 0; i < view.RowCount; i++)
{ 
    /* Move the focus for setting the error  */
    view.FocusedRowHandle = i;

    if (condition)
    {
        view.SetColumnError(view.Columns["NameOfColumn"],
                                         "Message", ErrorType.Critical);            
    }
}
```

I tried something similar, but doesn't work , my only achievement was that the last row with the focus show the error icon in the specified cells. I want to do this with the `SetColumnError`, but if there is another way to do it...

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the `Grid` inself can not store errors, this is the why only maintain the icon error for the `FocusedRow`, but you can implement certain `interface` and store all the errors for each rows.

The name of the `interface` is [`IDataErrorInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.idataerrorinfo.aspx), thisp rovides the functionality to offer custom error information that a user interface can bind to.

Here's an example of using this interface :

```
public class MyModel : IDataErrorInfo
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Stores error descriptions for the properties.
    /// </summary>
    Hashtable propertyErrors;

    /// <summary>
    /// Stores an error description for the item.
    /// </summary>
    String fNoteError;

   /// <summary>
   /// Gets and sets an error for the current item
   /// </summary>
   internal string NoteError
   {
       get { return fNoteError; }
       set
       {
           if (fNoteError != null && fNoteError == value) return;
           fNoteError = value;
       }
    }

    //Returns an error description set for the item's property
    string IDataErrorInfo.this[string columnName]
    {
        get
        {
           return GetColumnError(columnName);
        }
    }

    //Returns an error description set for the current item
    string IDataErrorInfo.Error
    {
        get { return NoteError; }
    }   

    public String NameOfColumnA { get; set; }
    public String NameOfColumnB { get; set; }

    public MyModel()
    {
       propertyErrors = new Hashtable { { "NameOfColumnA", "" }, { "NameOfColumnB", "" }};
       fNoteError = "";
    }     

    //Sets an error for an item's property
    public void SetColumnError(string elem, string error)
    {
        if (propertyErrors.ContainsKey(elem))
        {
            if ((string)propertyErrors[elem] == error) return;
            propertyErrors[elem] = error;
        }
    }

    //Gets an error for an item's property
    public string GetColumnError(string elem)
    {
       if (propertyErrors.ContainsKey(elem))
          return (string)propertyErrors[elem];
       else
          return "";
    }

    public void ClearErrors()
    {
       SetColumnError("NameOfColumnA", "");
       SetColumnError("NameOfColumnB", "");           
       NoteError = "";
    }
}
```

The above code define a model for your `Grid` with two columns which may contain errors. Then in you `UserControl` class you have to do it something like this :

```
public partial class UsDesiredName : UserControl3
{
    //Some code for your class

    private void ValidateData()
    {
        var data = gc_view.DataSource as List<MyModel>;
        foreach (var item in data)
        {                
            item.ClearErrors();
            if (condition for columnA)
            {
                item.NoteError = "Required fields.";
                item.SetColumnError("NameOfColumnA", "Required field.");                                       
            }  

            if (condition for columnB)
            {
                item.NoteError = "Required fields.";                    
                item.SetColumnError("NameOfColumnB", "Required field.");                    
            }    
        }
    }

    private void gc_view_ValidateRow(object sender, DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base.ValidateRowEventArgs e)
    {
        ValidateData()
    }
}
```

I hope this can be useful to someone as it was for me.

Comment: In order to make this work for me, I had to set each row to focused within the loop, otherwise the errors would not display until the rows became focused. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid the `GridView.SetColumnError()` can be used only for focused row.

To satisfy your requirements you have to implement it manually using the `GridColumn.ImageIndex` and `ColumnView.Images` properties, to display an icon in a column header.

Comment: Look if this DevExpress example suits your needs: [link](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Example/Details/E1997)